# How to extract "installed" file structure from Fedora LiveCD

Tags: ubuntu, extract, fedora, live-cd

This isnt strictly speaking programming but who understands Linux better than programmers who program on it?
Essentially I want to be able to extract the final file structure from a LiveCD without having to go through the entire install. I suppose its stored in one of the img files. Checked the isolinux img file, gunzipped it and cpio'ed, but I dont believe thats the version deployed onto hard disk, as boot and some other folders are missing. It would make preparing PXE boot servers much easier and faster...
Thx a lot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It might not be entirely possible. I'm not familiar with the precise Fedora installation process, but many operating systems build a file structure that is unique to the device it is being installed on. There is little to no reason to copy over all possible drivers or features when a given system has no way of using them (for example, if a processor doesn't support various Virtualization features you wouldn't want to put binaries on the system that require those features). I would expect that the Fedora installer probably does at least some minimal customization based on the hardware configuration of the system.

That said, you'd probably get better results over in superuser or serverfault. I'm sure that there are Linux administrators who have set up something similar to what you want.